# Type-parameter-only method overloading in scala

Tags: scala, generics, types, overloading, akka-http

Can I somehow achieve behaviour like this in scala (funcs has the same name and params but differs only at return type and type parameter)?

```scala
def a(i:Int): Int //1
def a[T](i: Int): Double //2

a(1) //call 1
a[Any](1) //call 2
```

**UPD motivation:**

I'm writing akka-http directive `auth`, which checks session and authorization of user request depending of permission parameters.

1. When it gets just a permission, it provides just authenticated `User`:

`def auth(perm: String): Directive1[User]`

2. When it gets a `Tuple` of permission with `UUID`, it gets (somehow) required object by this `UUID`, checks permission applied to required object and provides this object as well as `User`:

`def auth[Entity](tup: (String, UUID)): Directive1[(User, Entity)]`

3. **And** when it get a same `Tuple` but without type-parameter, it should check permission applied to required object but provide only authenticated `User`:

`def auth(tup: (String, UUID)): Directive1[User]`

The idea is to have same directive name for all cases but it seems that it is not possible to distinct between `a[T](i: Int): Int` and `a(i: Int): Double` at language level (due to type erasure).

Maybe there are some tricks using `implicits` that helps to achieve this?

Comment: What is the use case? What is the point of `T` if it doesn't represent anything.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez pls check the question, I updated motivation

Comment: The motivation appears to be "to have same directive name for all cases", but why is it important that they have the same name when they do different things and are called in different ways?

Comment: @Tim they all do authentication and authorization, the difference is only that one of them provides `Entity`

Comment: The one that returns an entity does something different from the one that just does authentication, which is a very good reason to give it a different name. Why is it necessary for them to have the same name? This is starting to feel like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @Tim Coz all security things can be done in single call and it's not important for caller will they load from db or not. The subject of question is "how to overload methods just by type in scala?", not about the quality of architecture

Comment: How does the method knows how to return a value of `Entity`? I would expect that method to receive an implicit parameter related to `Entity` and that would remove the ambiguity. It looks like that method does some black magic inside.

Comment: The question is about why you can't give the same name to three different methods, so I think it is reasonable to ask why you can't give them different names.

Answer (score 0):

Due to type erasure these 2 methods would have the same signature.

```
@ class Test {
  def a(i:Int): Int = 1
  def a[T](i: Int): Double = 2.0
  }
defined class Test

@ new Test()
res24: Test = ammonite.$sess.cmd23$Test@7441edeb

@ new Test().a(1)
cmd25.sc:1: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method a in class Test of type [T](i: Int)Double
and  method a in class Test of type (i: Int)Int
match argument types (Int)
val res25 = new Test().a(1)
                       ^
Compilation Failed
```

If you changed anything e.g. how you apply arguments, it should be doable:

```
@ class Test {
  def a(i:Int): Int = 1
  def a()(i: Int): Double = 2.0
  }
defined class Test

@ new Test().a(1)
res26: Int = 1

@ new Test().a()(1)
res27: Double = 2.0
```

So... depending on how much and what you are able to change, yes or no. In general it is bad idea though. Rarely you have a good reason to overload a method and overloading in this exact case is almost certainly an anti-pattern.

Comment: I was checking also two parameters but with `implicit` like:
```def a[T](i: Int)(implicit numeric: Numeric[T]): Double = ???```

Comment: It would have different signature after erasure so it should work. Still no idea why one  would be trying to achieve that in the first place.

Comment: Yes, that's strange why not to write one generic function, or give different name ))

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok pls check question, I updated motivation

Comment: @Bob nice catch with implicit parameter but it seems not suitable with akka-http directive because code block with extractor-func whould be treated as implicit parameter

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try disambiguating with type *ascription* like so

```
def a(i:Int): Int = 1
def a[T](i: Int): Double = 2

a(1): Int // res0: Int = 1
a[Any](1) // res1: Double = 2.0
```

Comment: First case results to error: `type mismatch; found: Double, required: Int`

Comment: @mopdobopot; You'll have to be more specific. This code, submitted by @MarioGalic, passes my tests without fail and it directly answers your original question (before the mods).

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake, @MarioGalic code works just fine but unfortunately not suitable for my case

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a little bit generic approach:

```
def add(a: Int): Int = a + 1
def add[T](a: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): Double = {
  num.toDouble(a) + 2.3
}

println(add(5)) // 6
println(add[Int](6)) // 8.3
```

The example on [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Bunyod/F37uEd4iQxapDx3tDZlwoQ/20)

Comment: nice idea with implicit param but it is not suitable in my case, I updated a question, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) issue here.

Authorising a user and extracting data are different things, so I would handle them as two different operations: a directive to authorise a user and a database method to load data for that user. The main advantage of this is that you can authorise a user for a set of endpoints in one operation.

This is simple example of what might work:

```
def route =
  auth { authUser =>
    (pathEnd | pathSingleSlash) {
      concat(
        get {
          val data = load(authUser, staticUuid)

          ???
        },
        post {
          decodeRequest {
            entity(as[MyRequestBody]) { myRequest =>
              val data = load(authUser, myRequest.uuid)

              ???
            }
          }
        },
      )
    }
  }
```

If it is awkward to pass `authUser` to methods all the time, make it an `implicit` of the data extraction methods. And you can make the load operation a directive as well, but a different directive from `auth`.

It may seem more verbose this way, but the person looking at your code in two year's time will thank you for making the code easy to understand. And that person is probably going to be you.

Comment: I have a separate authService which returns me set of rights and `User` object (authService storing users) altogether in one response. Then on business side special client checks this rights (maybe according to business object required for this). And this client loads object from db by himself, it knows which object required for which right. The thing that I want is to provide this object to the next code without one more request to database

Comment: Right, so the `auth` directive returns the `User` from the authService, and the `load` method checks the rights and loads the object from the db.